# Refresh the webpage, while the webpage is not loaded properly in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a program that extracts data from website and keeps in a spreadsheet. But the major problem I am encountering is the hanging of Internet Explorer.

```
With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate urll
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            Application.StatusBar = "Opening Page : " & i & ", Please wait..."
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set html = .Document
End With
```

The loop Do While sometimes sticks and never ends as the internet explorer is not able to load properly and never comes to readystate of 4. In this case I have to either refresh the page manually (keeping visibility of ie true) or I have to stop the program, and do some updates to program (locations of source and destination of data). This is pretty time consuming if every 10th webpage is keeping the loop open.

I have one solution, i.e. during the time loop goes on the program should check about the time elapsed during the loop execution, if the loop continues for more than 50 secs, the program should suspend the current loop and start again by refreshing page. (Please let me know if you have a better logic).

I am not able to do a correct coding for this job. Can anyone solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**UNTESTED**)

What this does is increments a variable and checks for the number of time the loop was called.

```
Dim nCount As Long

Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate urll
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            Application.StatusBar = "Opening Page : " & i & ", Please wait..."

            Wait 2 '<~~ Wait for 2 Seconds

            If nCount > 25 Then
                '~~> Approx 50 seconds have elapsed
            End If
        Loop
        Set HTML = .Document
    End With
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
    nCount = nCount + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Just one amendment, the ncount should be set to 0 each time the loop checking the value to be greater than 25, so that if the condition satisfies, the webpage does not refresh after every 2 secs...